# How many custom domains be hosted per GCP account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns-hosting, google-app-engine

I have GCP account AxyzTxyz.com (masked) for which i also have google workspace account.

In this GCP account, i have multiple projects, each would have their web domain. e.g. project 1 will have [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com), project 2 will have [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com) etc.

I am told that for each domains - domain1 and domain2 - IAM requires @domain1.com @domain2 email ids. I just want to use @AxyzTxyz.com email id for IAMs

Please clarify for me.

Many thanks!
Jaideep

Comment: Do you mean how many domains for websites, APIs, etc.? I am not aware of a limit for that item. You will have other quotas such as CPU that will affect you. Individual services such as HTTP(S) Load Balancers have limits on the number of names per certificate per service that are supported. Edit your question to provide more details on what you are configuring.

Comment: When i tried, for each domain name (one per project), it seemed like i needed email address with that domain name. 

I want to use my company email id  to manage all the projects with domain names.

Comment: You will need to set up a Google Cloud Organization using your Google Workplace domain name. Then you can create any number of projects within your quota limits (defaults to five).

Comment: Edit your question to be clear on what problem you are trying to solve. As written it is very confusing.

Comment: Hi John, truly appreciate you trying to help. I have tried to rephrase the question. Hope it makes it easier to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to use @AxyzTxyz.com email id for IAMs

If you want to use a business email for your Google Cloud Projects, then you need to set up a Google Cloud Organization. This requires either a Google Workspace or Cloud Identity account setup with the business domain name you wish to use.

[Creating and managing organizations](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization)

Since you already have a Google Workspace account providing your business email, setting up an organization is easy.

[Organization setup wizard](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-setup)